# Remove header & footer from published Google Docs Spreadsheet

Tags: css, layout, spreadsheet, documentation

I found javascript solution for removing gridlines on Google docs spreadsheets (using "download as HTML" and then past javascript in Web Address Bar): works great !!

```
javascript:var v="none",e="defaultView",o="border",m="Color",w=function(a,b){if(document[e]){if(document[e].getComputedStyle(a,null)[o+b+m]=="rgb(204, 204, 204)")a.style[o+b]=v}else if(a.currentStyle[o+b+m]=="#ccc")a.style[o+b]="none"},q=function(a){a=window.document.getElementsByTagName(a);for(var b=0;b<a.length;b++){var c=a[b];w(c,"Left");w(c,"Right");w(c,"Bottom");w(c,"Top")}};q("td");q("table");
```

Was wondering if it is possible to make a comparable javascript to remove the header and footer for docs "publised" to the web?! 
Published spreadsheets have a 
-> header: filename + sheetname; 
-> footer: "Edit this page (if you have permission) – Published by Google Docs – Report Abuse – Updated automatically every 5 minutes"
-> example: [TEST](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=t1T0Cn0TpkABxkOg1ytFEiQ&output=html&gridlines=false) (I already added "&gridlines=false" to the url to remove gridlines).

*Why is previous solution not sufficient ?!*
*I want some people to view and print the result of a spreadsheet (via publish to web) without giving them access (view) to the spreadsheet itself. Therefore they can't use "download as HTML" + your javascript, but want to provide a url to view a published site and be able to make a neat print without the Google header and footer.*

Would be great if anyone could help out!

Regards,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the linked example is no longer available, making the question unclear for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfully the layout on this page is super simple.

```
<div id="header">...</div>
<div id="content">...</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

You could write a function like this to hide the header and footer.

```
var f = function(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
};
f("header");
f("footer");
```

Or the copy paste version:

```
javascript:var f=function(id){document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";};f("header");f("footer");
```

Answer (score 3):

I built an app that does just this + improves the default layout. Check it out: http://gdoc.pub

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18537803)

Comment: Well, this is a web app so if the link dies, the solution dies along. Better update the post if so I reckon. Otherwise I could bring all the app's marketing here but I don't think this would be very SO-friendly either...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `range` parameter to get rid of the headers and footers, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371366/google-spreadsheet-without-header-and-footer/14676658#14676658).