# Google spreadsheet without header and footer

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I want to embed a Google spreadsheet without the header and footer. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123764/remove-header-footer-from-published-google-docs-spreadsheet) shows the trick, but doesn't say how to apply it. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<iframe id="embeddedthing" width='500' height='300' frameborder='0' src='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=<DocId>&single=true&gid=12&output=html&widget=false&gridlines=false'></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var f = function(id) {document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";};
  f("header");
  f("footer");
</script>
```

Then I thought I should apply it to the document loaded in the iframe, so I tried to access it using `document.getElementById('FrameId').contentWindow.document`, but the browser says "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame" and doesn't allow me to continue.

What is the correct way to run that JavaScript function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to remove headers and footers from a shared Google sheet in an iframe is to specify the sheet and the range to show.
With the following syntax a sheet appears nice and clean, with the exception of a thin gray border on the top and left edge:

`src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=<DocID>&gid=<SheetID>&gridlines=false&range=A1:Z100"`

Without the `range` parameter the behavior is affected by the `widget=true` to show a header row on top or `widget=false` to show headers, footers and links to the other sheets.
If the specified `range` is larger than the actual sheet size, the whole sheet is used. So `range=A1:Z100` will cover most cases with small tables.

Creating two adjacent iframes allows to do something similar to the frozen column or row headers.
Here is an example of a page that uses this technique to display 2 fixed columns with the headers on the left and a scrollable area on the right:

```
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <iframe width="103" height="187" frameborder="0" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AqEyi7du69LQdHRJXzViMlhEdHVYY2E4X1hnZ21EQ2c&gid=29&gridlines=false&range=A1:B999"></iframe>
    </td>
    <td>
      <iframe width="600" height="187" frameborder="0" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AqEyi7du69LQdHRJXzViMlhEdHVYY2E4X1hnZ21EQ2c&gid=29&gridlines=false&range=C1:CC999"></iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[This](http://stefanomenci.com/pool/index.php?pageId=3) is the website that uses this technique.

**EDIT**

Google has changed something and my website is suddenly broken.

The solution as suggested [here](https://wp-glogin.com/2014/08/embedding-google-spreadsheets-with-more-control-over-appearance/) is to add `&widget=false&chrome=false`.

Answer (score 0):

Because JS restricts access to frames, you would need to somehow fetch the HTML of the spreadsheet and remove the header and footer from within the page.

You could use a hidden `iframe` (`display: none;`) to house the spreadsheet, and then have a second `iframe` loaded with a page that fetches the HTML of the spreadsheet with [this method (requires jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8814538/1979005), then removes the header and footer. You could do this by getting the HTML, [parsing it into a DOM structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3104237/1979005), adding in a `script` element with the f() code, and then using a `data:` URL to pull up the page.

You could use a `base` element to preserve links to files; prepend the spreadsheet's original path (but NOT filename) to the `base`'s `href` if present; otherwise make a new `<base href="www.google.com/path/to/spreadsheet/without/filename/" />` in the `head`. You could fetch the path with a regex on the hidden `iframe`'s `src`.

May be a bit clunky and certainly could use improvement... but it (hopefully) works!!

Note that this is untested and based on research.